# codeigniter login system security issue

Tags: codeigniter

I have simple login system created in codeigniter.

In this after user login he is directed to controller "site.php" and function "members_area" having session check and directed to the view "members_area.php" .....
But if the user without login goes to my view page by url "http://localhost/reg_login/site/members_area"

1. **site.php**(Constructor)

   ```
   function members_area(){
       $this->is_logged_in();
       $this->load->view('members_area');
   }
   function is_logged_in(){
       $is_logged_in=$_SESSION['is_logged_in'];
       if(!isset( $is_logged_in)|| $is_logged_in!=true){
           redirect('login\index');
       }
   }
   ```

2.**member_area.php**(view)

```
<h3>Hello You have successfully logged in!!!!!!!</h3></body>
```

There is a security issue as I have no checks in the members_area.php.

Kindly help with security issue.

Comment: You have incorrect slash in redirect function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
function members_area(){
    if ( ! $this->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('login/index', 'refresh');
        exit;
    } else {
        $this->load->view('members_area');
    }

}
function is_logged_in(){
    $is_logged_in=$_SESSION['is_logged_in'];
    if (!isset( $is_logged_in)|| $is_logged_in!=true){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```